# The right motor on my line sensor Arduino robot runs even when the requirements to run it are not met

Tags: arduino

So in this Arduino code for a line sensor robot using RedBot line sensors, the right motor seems to be running even when both sensors are detecting black (a line). This does not happen on the right motor so I suspect it has something to do with the first "if" statement.

The motor does stop however when only the right sensor detects black and this makes only the left motor run. I'm not sure what the problem is that is making the right motor run even when its condition isn't met and this is not a problem with the sensor btw. I am using an L293D motor driver to control the motors but I doubt it has anything to do with that.

```
#include <RedBot.h>

RedBotSensor right_sen = RedBotSensor(A5);  
RedBotSensor left_sen = RedBotSensor(A4); 
int lineStandard = 650;
int motorPinRight = 12;
int motorPinLeft = 10;

void setup()  
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPinRight, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPinLeft, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("IR Sensor Readings:: ");
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  if(left_sen.read() > lineStandard) {
   left();
   digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  } else if(right_sen.read() > lineStandard) {
    right();
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  } else if((left_sen.read() < lineStandard) && (right_sen.read() < lineStandard)) {
    forward();
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  } else if((left_sen.read() > lineStandard) && (right_sen.read() > lineStandard)) {
    halt();
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  } else {
    halt();
  }
  delay(10);
}

void forward() {
  digitalWrite(motorPinRight, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPinLeft, HIGH);
}

void left() {
  digitalWrite(motorPinRight, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorPinLeft, LOW);
}

void right() {
  digitalWrite(motorPinRight, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPinLeft, HIGH);
}

void halt() {
  digitalWrite(motorPinRight, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPinLeft, LOW);
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if you suspect the order of the ifs matters, try reordering them to see if that confirms your suspicion.

Comment: I have tried switching the left motor and right motor and yes, the order of the ifs do seem to be the problem, the first statement seems to keep repeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with the order of your tests:

```
 if(left_sen.read() > lineStandard){ /* ...*/ }
 else if(right_sen.read() > lineStandard){ /* ...*/ }
 else if((left_sen.read() < lineStandard) && (right_sen.read() < lineStandard)) { /* ...*/ }
 else if((left_sen.read() > lineStandard) && (right_sen.read() > lineStandard)) 
     { /* this block cannot be reached, because of first test  */ 
       /* should be moved to first position, because it's more */
       /* restrictive than both tests 1 and 2                  */ }
 else { /* ...*/ }
```

To avoid this problem, you should reorder your tests starting with the most restrictive conditions first, or rewrite your code using a switch statement, which will make the code clearer.

```
#define LEFT_DETECT  (1 << 0)
#define RIGHT_DETECT (1 << 1)
// ...


void movementControl()
{
    char detect;
    detect = (left_sen.read() > lineStandard) ? LEFT_DETECT : 0;
    detect += (right_sen.read() > lineStandard) ? RIGHT_DETECT : 0;

    switch(detect)
    {
    case LEFT_DETECT:
        left(); 
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
        break;

    case RIGHT_DETECT:
        right();
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
        break;

    default:
    case LEFT_DETECT + RIGHT_DETECT:
         halt();
         break;

    case 0:
        forward();
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);  
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I put the halt argument in the first "if" and that seems to fix it as having that repeat is fine, thanks.

Comment: Since you have 2 conditions, you should put tests with 2 conditions firsts, and with a preference to AND operations first.  That's how the logic works.  The switch/case format is how this kind of decision-taking is done in real-life industrial applications.  There are very good reasons for that.